# How do I apply an array of custom taxonomy terms to a searchable dropdown list?

Tags: php, wordpress, dropdown

I have a searchable dropdown list code.  Here's the code in jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/d9acx502/1/#&togetherjs=LpI6l02DNs

I have a plugin code that displays the dropdown list (not searchable) on the page.  Here is the code.

```js
        <?php if ( $has_location && $can_search_by_location ) : ?>
          <!-- Location field -->
   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
             <label><?php esc_html_e( 'Select location', 'custom-plugin' ); ?></label>
    <?php 
    cp_dropdown_terms(array(
     'show_option_none'  => '-- ' . esc_html__( 'Select location', 'custom-plugin' ) . ' --',
     'option_none_value' => (int) $general_settings['base_location'],
     'base_term'         => max( 0, (int) $general_settings['base_location'] ),
     'parent'            => max( 0, (int) $general_settings['base_location'] ),
     'taxonomy'          => 'cp_locations',
     'name'        => 'l',
     'class'             => 'form-control',
     'orderby'         => sanitize_text_field( $locations_settings['orderby'] ), 
     'order'          => sanitize_text_field( $locations_settings['order'] ),
     'selected'          => isset( $_GET['l'] ) ? (int) $_GET['l'] : -1
    ));
    ?>
    
    </div>
         <?php endif; ?>
```

How do I apply the plugin's custom taxonomy array to the dropdown instead of using the  options?

Comment: Please don't create duplicate posts. you already [asked this question yesterday here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62248575/how-do-i-use-a-taxonomy-array-from-a-plugin-instead-listing-options-in-dropdown). If you have new information, you can edit that question to update it.

Comment: Sorry.  I tried to delete it, but I couldn't figure out how.